# Vectorizing a Numpy slice operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have a Numpy vector,

```
A = zeros(100)
```

and I divide it into subvectors by a list of breakpoints which index into `A`, for instance,

```
breaks = linspace(0, 100, 11, dtype=int)
```

So the `i`-th subvector would be lie between the indices `breaks[i]` (inclusive) and `breaks[i+1]` (exclusive).
The breaks are not necessarily equispaced, this is only an example.
However, they will always be strictly increasing.

Now I want to operate on these subvectors. For instance, if I want to set all elements of the `i`-th subvector to `i`, I might do:

```
for i in range(len(breaks) - 1):
    A[breaks[i] : breaks[i+1]] = i
```

Or I might want to compute the subvector means:

```
b = empty(len(breaks) - 1)
for i in range(len(breaks) - 1):
    b = A[breaks[i] : breaks[i+1]].mean()
```

And so on.

How can I avoid using `for` loops and instead vectorize these operations?

Comment: Is `breaks` pre-sorted?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, they are strictly increasing.

Comment: Also, would the limits of breaks cover the entire `A`, i.e. could there be some elements of A that won't be changed after this operation?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, they will cover all of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't a single answer to your question, but several techniques that you can use as building blocks. Another one you may find helpful:

All numpy ufuncs have a [`.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) method, which you can use to your advantage for some of your calculations:

```
>>> a = np.arange(100)
>>> breaks = np.linspace(0, 100, 11, dtype=np.intp)
>>> counts = np.diff(breaks)
>>> counts
array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
>>> sums = np.add.reduceat(a, breaks[:-1], dtype=np.float)
>>> sums
array([  45.,  145.,  245.,  345.,  445.,  545.,  645.,  745.,  845.,  945.])
>>> sums / counts  # i.e. the mean
array([  4.5,  14.5,  24.5,  34.5,  44.5,  54.5,  64.5,  74.5,  84.5,  94.5])
```

Comment: This was the closest to what I was looking for, but really I just want the slices used by reduceat--I don't actually want to reduce these slices! For that matter, I don't even have a ufunc. Is there something that would simply return the slices computed by reduceat and do so in a vectorized way? In my case all of the slices are the same length.

Answer (score 7):

You can use simple [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) -

```
import numpy as np

# Form zeros array of same size as input array and 
# place ones at positions where intervals change
A1 = np.zeros_like(A)
A1[breaks[1:-1]] = 1

# Perform cumsum along it to create a staircase like array, as the final output
out = A1.cumsum()
```

Sample run -

```
In [115]: A
Out[115]: array([3, 8, 0, 4, 6, 4, 8, 0, 2, 7, 4, 9, 3, 7, 3, 8, 6, 7, 1, 6])

In [116]: breaks
Out[116]: array([ 0,  4,  9, 11, 18, 20])

In [142]: out
Out[142]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]..)
```

---

If you want to have mean values of those subvectors from `A`, you can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
mean_vals = np.bincount(out, weights=A)/np.bincount(out)
```

If you are looking to extend this functionality and use a *custom* function instead, you might want to look into MATLAB's [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) equivalent for `Python/Numpy`: `numpy_groupies` whose source code is available [here](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies).

Comment: I like your method; it is faster than mine. You could also use `A1 = np.zeros(breaks[-1])`.

Comment: This solves the simple use case of setting each subvector to be constant (which was meant as an example). What if, for example, I want to compute the mean of each subvector?

Comment: Your first method is what `np.unique` with the optional `return_inverse` argument [uses to do its thing](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.9.x/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L206). Nice!

Comment: @Jaime Yeah I guess its equivalent to that for sorted array. In MATLAB, we have a simliar thing with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with its third output argument. It's nice to see all these similarities!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [35]: np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(breaks)-1), np.diff(breaks))
Out[35]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
       6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9,
       9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9])
```

---

To compute arbitrary binned statistics you could use [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

breaks = np.linspace(0, 100, 11, dtype=int)
A = np.random.random(100)

means, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=np.arange(len(A)), values=A, statistic='mean', bins=breaks)
```

`stats.binned_statistic` can compute means, medians, counts, sums; or, 
to compute an arbitrary statistics for each bin, you can pass a callable to the `statistic` parameter:

```
def func(values):
    return values.mean()

funcmeans, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=np.arange(len(A)), values=A, statistic=func, bins=breaks)

assert np.allclose(means, funcmeans)
```

Comment: But how will I now set the `i`-th part to `i` while avoiding a for loop?