# R summary() equivalent in numpy

Tags: python, r, numpy

Is there an equivalent of `R`'s `summary()` function in `numpy`?

`numpy` has std, mean, average functions separately, but does it have a function that sums up everything, like `summary` does in `R`?

If found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637281/what-are-python-pandas-equivalents-for-r-functions-like-str-summary-and-he) question which relates to `pandas` and [this](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html) article with R-to-numpy equivalents, but it doesn't have what I seek for.

Comment: why is `describe()` from pandas not an option for you? `numpy` is not a statistics library. So a function that prints summary statistics is not really in scope.

Comment: Because I just had `numpy` installed and not `pandas`. Not that I can't install `pandas`, just thought that if `numpy` has statistics methods like `mean, std, var`, etc. why wouldn't it have a method to aggregate these statistics?

Comment: The solutions to [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894320/vectorizing-a-numpy-slice-operation) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**. You'll need to use `pandas`.

R is for language for statistics, so many of the basic functionality you need, like `summary()` and `lm()`, are loaded when you boot it up. Python has many uses, so you need to install and import the appropriate statistical packages. `numpy` isn't a statistics package - it's for numerical computation more generally, so you need to use packages like `pandas`, `scipy` and `statsmodels` to allow Python to do what R can do out of the box.

Answer (score 57):

#### 1. Load Pandas in console and load csv data file

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep = ",")
```

#### 2. Examine first few rows of data

```
data.head()
```

#### 3. Calculate summary statistics

```
summary = data.describe()
```

#### 4. Transpose statistics to get similar format as R summary() function

```
summary = summary.transpose()
```

#### 5. Visualize summary statistics in console

```
summary.head()
```

Comment: data.info() is another useful one

Comment: Useful, but not for numpy. Sometimes one just wants to overview the numpy arrays one makes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for details like summary() in R i.e

- 5 point summary for numeric variables
- Frequency of occurrence of each class for categorical variable

To achieve above in Python you can use df.describe(include= 'all').